# What's the difference between executing ss and sudo ss?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, sudo, ip

It's better use without sudo in some ocasions?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should run all commands as a regular user unless prompted to authenticate with your user password. That way if you make a mistake running the command it cannot change any files that are owned by root which  could possibly create a security risk.

In addition to the preceding caveat in general file manipulation and editing under root should be restricted to the command line. *Using sudo with graphical apps has the potential to corrupt your environment by allowing root to take ownership of and/or change permissions on critical files that you must own.*  <sup>[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)</sup>